# Why is texture is rotated wrongly in Rendered view, but fine in Material view?

Tags: texturing, uv, blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view

I am in Blender Render.

[image]

[image]

My texture also doesn't show up in Texture Viewport, it's all grey in there, so it may play a role as to what I am doing wrong.

:(

Comment: In the Map option click and change to UV map

Comment: @atek ah i see, that fixed iT, thanks! Btw, do you also know why my texture isnt showing up in texture viewport?